# FullCalendar first hour of the day in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

So i have encountered the following issue:
As you see in the screenshot, i add 2 events with difference of 1 minute. Both events start at the same Date/Time, but one ends at 08:59 AM and the other one at 09:00 AM (Same day), how comes the month view renders like this?

[image]

I suspect theres an first_our_of_day param that i should set in the month view, but i have seen nothing like this in the docs.

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
var calendar;
$(document).ready(function() {

    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // eventLimit: true,
        axisFormat: 'h:mm T',
        header:{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            event_id = calEvent.id;
            show_ticket_details(event_id);
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            today = new Date();
            selected_date = new Date(date.format() + "GMT -0500");
            selected_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            if (selected_date.getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
                new_ticket(date.format());
            }else{

            }
        },
        eventRender: function(event,element){
            title = "";
            var start_date = new Date(event.start);
            var start_hour = start_date.getHours() % 12 || 12;
            var start_minute = (start_date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + start_date.getMinutes()
            var start_ampm = (start_hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
            var start_date = start_hour + ":" + start_minute + "" + start_ampm;

            title = start_date;


            if (event.end != "") {
                var end_date = new Date(event.end);
                var end_hour = end_date.getHours() % 12 || 12;
                var end_minute = (end_date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + end_date.getMinutes()
                var end_ampm = (end_hour >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
                var end_date = end_hour + ":" + end_minute + "" + end_ampm;
                title = title + " - " + end_date;
            };
            element.find('.fc-content').parent().html(title + " - " + event.title);
        }
    });

            add_event(333,"February 02, 2015 00:00 -0500","February 06, 2015 09:00 -0500","Prueba concepto","#5cb85c")
            add_event(334,"February 02, 2015 00:00 -0500","February 06, 2015 08:59 -0500","Prueba concepto 2","#5cb85c")
});

function add_event(id,start,end,title,backgroundColor){
    var eventObject = new Object();
    eventObject.className = 'calendar_event'
    eventObject.id = id;
    eventObject.start = start;
    eventObject.end = end;
    eventObject.title = title;
    eventObject.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    eventObject.borderColor = "white";
    eventObject.allDay = false;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',eventObject,true);
}

function new_ticket(date){
    $.get('/tickets/new',{date: date},function(data){
        $("#modal_form_container").html(data);
        $("#modal_form").modal('show');
    });
}

function show_ticket_details(ticket_id){
    $.get('/tickets/' + ticket_id,function(data){
        $("#modal_form_container").html(data);
        $("#modal_form").modal('show');
    });
}
```

Edit 2: Here is my week view, as you can see, its working fine in this view.

[image]

Comment: What is your Timezone ? There maybe something like this going.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue I have added some code, as you can see i manually put my timezone in my events. I think we can discard timezone problems as in only 1 minute difference this happens

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue, Yes, already tried and it looks fine, Edited and added a screenshot

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue I have added the businessHours option starting at 05:00 to 23:00. Now in the week view works fine by shadowing the business hours, but still having the same behaviour in month view :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at full calendar code I've found this attribute :

```
nextDayThreshold: '09:00:00', // 9am
```

you may want to modify this one.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/

> When an event's end time spans into another day, the minimum time it must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day.
>   ... .
>   Only affects timed events that appear on whole-days. Whole-day cells occur in month view ...